# Word for Speaking abstractly

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for speaking of something made-up as if it were real? Like a character from a novel or movie?

Comment: Maybe **fantize** or **dream up**?

Comment: @SovereignSun you mean: fantasize.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain your question more precisely??

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean. Can you edit your question to give us an example context where the word would be used? (use the "Edit" button between your question and these comments)

Answer (score 0):

This could be speaking [in character](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--character)

> **Idioms**
>
> *26. in character*
>
> b. in accordance with the role or personality assumed in a performance

Comment: Or you could use **[speculatively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speculative)**. We speculated about life with today's technology, but without air travel.

Comment: @Davo Sounds like another good answer.  (One of the great things about English: there is usually more than one valid answer to this sort of question.)

Comment: I don't see how a dialogue is something made up that is not real. I think the question needs some work.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking "in character" works when it's an actor speaking, or a role-playing gamer speaking in game terms.

The more general term you want is "**in universe**". A common example would be any Star-Trek fan discussing issues as if Star Trek were real. This would include discussions of starship combat tactics, analysis of warp-physics, aspects of various alien races, or all of the different starship designs.

*They were having an in-universe physics debate.*

Comment: in universe is not a usual expression.

Comment: @Lambie Top Google hits for "in universe" confirm the phrase is common & accepted: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in-universe),[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InUniverse),[scifi.meta.stackexchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/what-does-in-universe-mean),[Urban dictionary(unreliable but useful)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=in-universe),[Wookiepedia (on-topic for this question)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/In-universe), [Wikipedia tag for in-universe content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:In-universe)